# How can I implement dynamic packet receiver in NetworkComms library?

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, client-server, networkcomms.net

So I am developing a Client-Server app using NetworkComms library in C#. Currently I am using the following to receive messages:

```
NetworkComms.AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler<string>(PacketType.PACKETTYPE_HANDSHAKE, (packetHeader, connection, input) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nA message was received from " + connection.ToString() + " which said '" + input + "'.");
            Console.WriteLine("PACKET HEADER = " + packetHeader);



            this.SendMessage(PacketType.PACKETTYPE_HANDSHAKE_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT, "HEHEHE!!", connection);
            //connection.SendObject(PacketType.PACKETTYPE_HANDSHAKE_ACKNOWLEDGEMENT, "ULOLZ");
        });
```

So this is the packet handler .. What I want to do is if I can do a condition first for determining what packet has been received so that I wouldn't keep using `AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler` method.

The following is the idea I want to implement:

1. Message has been received.
2. Check what packet has been received first.
3. If packet has been verified, do a specific action.

Right now, I keep implementing `AppendGlobalIncomingPacketHandler` but whenever I send new message with different packet type, it keeps going to the first I made which receives the HANDSHAKE packet.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: this may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840409/networkcomms-net-library-sending-custom-class

Comment: @Anil thank you. Let me try this out first. Thank you. :)